# $1+n! \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n k$ is prime for infinitely many $n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

> Prove that there are infinite natural numbers $ n $, such that $1+n! \cdot \sum_{k=1}^n k$ is a prime number.

I really have no idea for this problem. What do you suggest?

Comment: What is a "natural infinity"?

Comment: @Thorgott that there are natural infinities $ n $ given the problem

Comment: @EsposaDoYoongi I don't get what you mean by those words.

Comment: I think what you mean to say is that there are infintely many $n$ such that ... is prime.  Note that the sum is $\frac 12n(n+1)$ so you could write it more simply as $1+\frac 12n(n+1)n!$.    I doubt one can prove there are infinitely many.

Comment: Portuguese switches the order of adjectives and sustantives with respect to English. Surely the asker meant “infinite natural numbers”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I  think it is likely there are infinitely many such $n$, but I suspect a real proof is difficult if possible.  Here is a heuristic argument based on the density of primes.  Define $a(n)=1+\frac 12n(n+1)n!$  We expect the chance $a(n)$ is prime is $\frac 1{\log (a(n))}$  The number we expect above $n=10$ is then
$$\sum_{n=10}^\infty\frac 1{\log (a(n))}=\sum_{n=10}^\infty\frac 1{\log (1+\frac 12n(n+1)n!)}\\
\approx \sum_{n=10}^\infty\frac 1{n \log (n)-n+\frac 52\log (n)+\frac 12 \log(2\pi)-\log(2)}\\
\gt \sum_{n=10}^\infty\frac 1{n \log (n)}$$
which diverges.  Starting at $n=10$ just makes Stirling's approximation quite accurate and avoids taking $\log(1)=0$.